# How should a man and a woman behave after their divorce?

Tags: marriage, divorce

Is there any advice, recommendation or requirement for a behaviour after a divorce? Specially when a man wants to take a second wife, and his first wife got married and divorced meanwhile.

Comment: Hello @Dassi, what are the issues you are looking to know about Ie. Relationship with each other, how they are allowed to interact? Or am i missing other elements to your question?

Comment: I heard from a rav that since the Torah uses the term *kritut* which means "cut off", the two spouses should never contact each other for he rest of their lives. To me, this sounds a bit drastic, and is impractical if they have shared child custody. However, I do understand the origin of his thinking.

Comment: @DanF - Hard to digest, as it's a Mitzvah to remarry one's divorcee unless one is a Cohen or got divorced because "halacha forced one to".

Comment: @DannySchoemann [this gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.112a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) might explain it: the less one thinks of his previous wife, the better for both in the new couple

Comment: Dassi [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first interesting question. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: From the second part of your q it sounds like you're asking if there's any customary civil protocol, e.g. notifying the other of planned second marriage, general cordiality etc. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @DannySchoemann ...or unless she already married someone else

Comment: The first wife got involved with another man while married, then after getting a Get she got married and divorced the second husband, took her first husband’s surname back. Does a first husband have any obligation to her?

Comment: @Dassi Why should he? He paid the kesuvah and is totally *cut off* from her.

Answer (score 5):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch has 2 Halachot related to one's divorcee in [סימן קנב - אסור יחוד ושאר קרבות בנשים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0151_L2) - though it's irrelevant to him being remarried or not:

1. While divorcees may not live in the same courtyard, if she remarried and got divorced again then they need to be even further apart and may not even live in the same alleyway, if it's a cul-de-sac. 
   While she's remarried they may not even live in the same neighborhood. (*Neighborhood* as defined in Halacha. TBD.)
   Unless it's her courtyard, she has to move away from him.
2. One may financially support one's divorcee, and she takes precedence over other needy strangers.
   However, the support has to be delivered via a 3rd party, so that they don't deal directly with each other.

> **סעיף טו'**: 
>   מִי שֶׁגֵרַשׁ אֶת אִשְׁתּוֹ מִן הַנִּשׂוּאִין, לֹא תָדוּר עִמּוֹ בֶּחָצֵר. וְאִם הוּא כֹּהֵן, וְכֵן אֲפִלּוּ אִם הוּא יִשְֹרָאֵל **וְהִיא נִשֵּׁאת לְאַחֵר וְנִתְגָּרְשָׁה גַם מִמֶּנוּ**, וְכֵן מִי שֶׁגֵּרַשׁ אֶת אִשְׁתּוֹ מִשׁוּם שֶׁהִיא אֲסוּרָה לוֹ, כָּל אֵלּוּ צְרִיכִין הַרְחָקָה יְתֵרָה, וְלֹא תָדוּר עִמּוֹ בְמָבוֹי, אִם הוּא מָבוֹי סָתוּם. אֲבָל בְּמָבוֹי מְפֻלָּשׁ שֶׁדֶּרֶךְ הָרַבִּים עוֹבֵר בֵּינֵיהֶם, מֻתָּרִים לָדוּר. וּגְרוּשָׁה שֶׁנִשׂאת וְדָרָה עִם בַּעְלָהּ הַשֵנִי, אֵלּוּ צְרִיכִין עוֹד הַרְחָקָה יְתֵרָה, וְלֹא תָדוּר עִם בַּעְלָהּ הָרִאשׁוֹן בְכָל הַשְׁכוּנָה. בְּכָל אֵלּוּ הַהַרְחָקוֹת, הִיא נִדְחֵית מִפָּנָיו. אַךְ אִם הָיְתָה הֶחָצֵר שֶׁלָּהּ, הוּא נִדְחֶה מִפָּנֶיהָ. ‏
>
> **סעיף טז'**: 
>   מֻתָּר לְאָדָם לָזוּן גְרוּשָׁתוֹ, וּמִצְוָה הִיא יוֹתֵר מִבִּשְׁאָר עָנִי, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, וּמִבְּשָׂרְךָ לֹא תִתְעַלָּם. וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא לוֹ עֵסֶק עִמָּהּ, רַק יְזוּנָהּ עַל יְדֵי שְּׁלִיחַ. ‏

Comment: This is interesting info. Would you know if anyone (Shu"t, etc.) discusses situations where *Dina Demalchuta* might override. E.g. the court orders joint custody, or they order one of the spouses not to leave his city (e.g. s/he is an ex-con on probation)?

Comment: ".... **should** be endowed via a 3rd party" (the source is a *drashah* from that *passuk* but no such qualification is given; KSA also doesn't use such prohibitive terminology.)

Comment: The source for this halacha is Kesubos 28a.

Comment: @robev Was this comment (source) meant for me?

Comment: @Oliver just suggesting an improvement to Danny's answer.

Comment: @robev I see. I'm sure you can understand my query. Tho note, the source for the initiative to have a middleman is indeed from Kes. (re. retrieving a loan from an ex wife - and acc. to Rashi, the former husband being a Kohen) but the source for giving charity (not alimony) to an ex is the *drashah* I mentioned (VR 34:14)

Comment: @Oliver - what doesn't match וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא לוֹ עֵסֶק עִמָּהּ, רַק יְזוּנָהּ עַל יְדֵי שְּׁלִיחַ in my pseudo-translation? I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @DannySchoemann In line with 'כללי השו״ע/הפוסקים' the KSA's phraseology ("ובלבד שלא יהא... רק") doesn't seem to imply that it "has to be", rather "it should be". Or maybe said language guidelines don't apply to KSA; could be.